# Add my own function to Slickgrid DataView

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I would like extends the Slickgrid DateView to add a getter for the filterArgs, see https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/775/files.

Example of wrong code... :

```
(function($) {
    $.extend(Slick.Data.DataView, {
        "getFilterArgs": function getFilterArgs() {
             return filterArgs;
         }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Do you know the right way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems for me that the only possible way to fit your requirements is to use your own setter as well. Something like:

1. Extend `DataView` class with a new `getFilterArgs` method:

```
    Slick.Data.DataView.prototype.getFilterArgs = function () {
      return this._filterArgs;
    }
```

1. Create your own `setFilterArgsInternal` method and use it:

```
    Slick.Data.DataView.prototype.setFilterArgsInternal = function (args) {
      this.setFilterArgs.call(this, args);
      this._filterArgs = args;
    }
```

Again, everywhere after that use `setFilterArgsInternal` instead of `setFilterArgs`.